# Officially supported browsers

Tags: support

What browsers are officially supported? I have consistent problems using advanced features like pop-ups in Firefox 3.6 .

Comment: Dude, you're way past time to upgrade...

Comment: @ChrisS The 3.6.x is still officially supported by Mozilla. Not everyone is able to upgrade.

Comment: And having tried some of the newer versions I'd suggest not everyone want to "upgrade".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of supported browsers is [over on mSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). Your Firefox 3.6 is listed as

- Firefox 4 (and earlier) — probably unsupported (old version).